# android: eclipse does not load emulator device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I try to Run (or Debug) my project in eclipse, the AVD emulator emulator boots normally but eclipse doesn't recognise it. On DDMS, the Devices tab does not find the AVD emulator and thus I see no traffic in the LogCat. 
On the other hand, when I plug my phone and choose Run (or Debug) project, eclipse connects to the phone and works just fine (I see it on DDMS on LogCat shows traffic). Any thoughts on this one?

I'm using Eclipse_Galileo_5.2 and Google APIs (API level 12, Platform 3.1). I was working with the same setup before the problem appeared without any problems.

I highly appreciate all the help...

Comment: Goto your profile and open all question in new tab and accept the best answer of all question you ask...

Comment: Sorry for asking but, how do I "accept the best answer"? Is there some relevant button? I've opened all my questions but I fail to see an "accept" button. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh I just saw it. I simply tick the answers on the left hand side. How silly of me.....

Comment: I don't know what version of the ADT you have but you should note this from the Android SDK web page: "Note: Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run from command line `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`. ADB will reattach to the running emulator and will be able to work with it. Do not exit the emulator as bashu suggests as the problem is likely to appear again if you have a slower computer.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of time it happens to me also.
What i do is, I first **Exit** the Emulator. Then  kill adb using 
**`adb kill-server`** after that i **clean** the project. 
and then **`adb start-server`**
and finally **run** the application and it works fine for me.

Thanks.